# How to Joing two tables in codeigniter with where clause

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join, ambiguous

Please any one cal help me
My query is following

Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous

```
SELECT u_profile.*, u_user.* FROM u_profile JOIN u_user ON u_profile.id = u_user.id WHERE id = '1' AND u_profile.id = '1'
```

from where id = 1 is coming I don't know please can help me some one.

Comment: My query is following $this->db->select('u_profile.*,s_user.*');
  $this->db->from('u_profile');
  $this->db->where('u_profile.id', $userId);
  $this->db->join('u_user','u_user.id = u_profile.id');
  $result = $this->db->get();

Comment: You need to add `table name` before id `WHERE table.id='1' `

Comment: query with out the last id i mean  `SELECT u_profile.*, u_user.* FROM u_profile JOIN u_user ON u_profile.id = u_user.id WHERE u_profile.id = '1'`

Comment: Is your issue has resolved u didnt repond on answer yet

Answer (score 0):

You need to indicate the table name in your where clause, because SQL does not know what `id` is until you indicate the table to which it belongs. 
Assuming you want to find both user_id and profile_id :

```
SELECT u_profile.*, u_user.* FROM u_profile 
JOIN u_user ON u_profile.id = u_user.id 
WHERE u.user_id = '1' AND u_profile.id = '1';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like that in CodeIgniter **For INNER JOIN**:

```
$this->db->select();
$this->db->from('u_profile')->join('u_user', 'u_profile.id = u_user.id');
$this->db->where('u_user.id',1);
$this->db->where('u_profile.id',1);
```

For **LEFT JOIN** use this:

```
$this->db->select();
$this->db->from('u_profile')->join('u_user', 'u_profile.id = u_user.id','left');
$this->db->where('u_user.id',1);
$this->db->where('u_profile.id',1);
```

And `Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous` means, you have two column with same in both table like id, so you need to use as **u_user.id** AND **u_profile.id**.